# Application of the complex Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $A$ be a nonempty set, and let $X=[0,1]^A$. The algebra generated by the coordinate maps $\pi_{\alpha}: X\to[0,1]$ and the constant function 1 is dense in $C(X)$.

How to prove it? I try to use the complex Stone-Weierstrass theorem.
Check:

> (1) $\mathcal{A}$ generated by coordinate maps is a closed complex subalgebra of $C(X)$
>
> (2) separates points

How to show $\pi(x_2)=\pi(x_1)$ then $x_1=x_2$?

> (3) closed under complex conjugation.

Here is my proof:
Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be the subalgebras of $C(X)$ and $C(X, R)$, respectively, generated by the coordinate maps and the constant function 1. Then $\mathcal{A}= span_{\mathbb{C}}(B)$, because $\mathcal{A}$ contains B and $span_{\mathbb{C}}(B)$ is an algebra. Because complex conjugation is continuous, A is also closed under complex conjugation. If $x_1, x_2 \in X$ and $x_1 \neq x_2$,
then $π_{\alpha}(x_1) \neq \pi_{\alpha}(x_2)$, and hence $\mathcal{A}$ separates points.

By Tychonoff’s theorem, X is compact, and it is also Hausdorff because $[0, 1]$ is Hausdorff. Since $\mathcal{A}$ contains the constant functions, the complex Stone-Weierstraß theorem implies that $\mathcal{A} = C(X).$

Comment: Think about what happens when $|A| = 2$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Closed under complex conjugation is immediate, because each of the functions generating the algebra $\mathcal A$ is real-valued. So you really only need to show that it separates points. In other words, if $f,g:A\rightarrow [0,1]$ are any two functions (elements of $X$) such that $\pi_\alpha(f)=\pi_\alpha(g)$ for all $\alpha\in A$, show that $f=g$. To prove this, recall that the definition of the coordinate map $\pi_\alpha$ is simply $\pi_\alpha(f)=f(\alpha)$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: How to prove it contains constant?

Comment: This is given in the question. It asks that the algebra $\mathcal A$ generated by the coordinate projections and $\textit{and the constant map } 1$ is dense. So you are already given that $\mathcal A$ contains 1.

Comment: Do I need to prove that $\mathcal{A}=Span_{\mathbb{C}}(\mathcal{B})$ which $\mathcal{B})$ is generated by constant. Does $\mathcal{A}$ generated by $C(X, \mathbb{C})$?

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these are true. The algebra $\mathcal A$ is pretty clearly a proper subspace of more than one dimension. I would recommend that you revisit the specifications of the problem. Take a step back and consider: where is the linear algebra; where is the topology? What properties of $X$ and $\mathcal A$ do I need to prove in order to appeal to Stone-Weierstrass?

Comment: I feel like you do not understand my idea. Please see my new edit. I write my idea and solution.

Comment: I can prove $\mathcal{A}=span(\mathcal{B})$.

Comment: So we can just use the (real)Stone-Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: Yes, I see now. This argument works. You are using the complex SW-theorem. Note: if $x_1,x_2\in X$ and $x_1\neq x_2$, then $\textit{there exists some }\alpha\in A$ with $x_1(\alpha)\neq x_2(\alpha)$. For this particular $\alpha,$ we have $\pi_\alpha(x_1)\neq \pi_\alpha(x_2)$.

Comment: But how to show $\mathcal{A}$ is closed? Take $x_n\to x$, show that $\pi(x_n)\to \pi(x)$. Is coordinate function continuous?

Comment: Yes, the coordinate functions $\pi_\alpha:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ are certainly continuous. The product topology on $X$ is defined to be the coarsest topology for which all of these maps are continuous. But I don't understand why you want to show that $\mathcal A$ is closed. This is not a condition of the SW-theorem. You are trying to show that $\mathcal A$ is dense in $C(X,\mathbb C)$, so it can't be closed in this space unless it $\textit{is}$ the whole space, which is not the case.

Comment: But in Folland's textbook. The condition of SW-theorem is including $\mathcal{A}$ is a closed subalgebra of $C(X,\mathbb{R})$.